# Can I format a smarty token number to have thousands comma?

Tags: smarty

Based upon smarty documentation I should be able to do something like this

```
{contribution.total_amount|number_format:2:".":","}
```

and get something like 1,234.56, but it shows blank.  In the logs I see:

```
[plugin] (secure mode) modifier 'number_format' is not allowed 
(core.load_plugins.php, line 118) in Smarty->trigger_error() (line 1094 
of  .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php).
```

In searching our code tree a bit, I find a plugin modifier.crmNumberFormat.php, which looks like it should be the one. So why isn't it using it?

I do see that there are two Smarty plugin directories.  Not sure which one it's using.  There is one in sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty and another in sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty

We're running 4.5.8 and have 4.6.7 in a dev environment.

Answer (score 5):

The civi provided modifier has a different name: crmNumberFormat

moreover as per Paul-Tahoe analysis, smarty seems to be confused, so the trick is to assign the formatted value to a temporary variable:

```
{assign var="ttl" value=$contact.total_amount|crmNumberFormat:2:'.':','}

and then display it:{$ttl}
```

Comment: After a fashion it works.  It doesn't work in place like shown. It throws a "syntax error: unrecognized tag:" 

I had to assign it to a var.  {assign var="ttl" value=$contact.total_amount|crmNumberFormat:2:'.':','}Total Amount:{$ttl}

Comment: aah good point, I'm fixing the answer, thanks!